# node.js setup http proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js

i typed according to Node.js book, but can't work in IE or chrome.
can anyone check where is the problem?
below is the code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var server = http.createServer(function (sreq, sres) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(sreq.url);
    var opts = {
        host: "www.163.com",
        port: 80,
        path: url_parts.pathname,
        headers: sreq.headers
    };
    var creq = http.get(opts, function (cres) {
        sres.writeHead(cres.statusCode, cres.headers);
        cres.pipe(sres);
    });

    sreq.pipe(creq);
});
server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    console.log("listening" + server.address().port + "......");
});
```

Comment: What url are you trying to acces it on? You create a server with hostname `www.163.com`, but then let it listen on 127.0.0.1. I'm by far not a NodeJS expert, but this seems odd to me. Also, provide more info. What doesn't work? Nothing gets printed? Crashes? Etc

Comment: hi, it is  proxy, not create a server of 163.com.  i create localhost proxy and request to www.163.com.(you can change to any known websites, such as www.google.com too, but firewall in China).   this proxy will send request to the target website and get data and show through localhost proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the remote server, `www.163.com`, requires a proper `Host` header to be set. With your code, you're sending the `Host` header that is passed by the browser to your server; in other words, `127.0.0.1:1337` (or possibly `localhost:1337`).

Try changing the header to the target host:

```
var opts = {
    host: "www.163.com",
    port: 80,
    path: url_parts.pathname,
    headers: sreq.headers
};
opts.headers.host = 'www.163.com';
...
```

Comment: but there is still question. if `opts.host` is different from `opts.headers.host`. response data will go with `opts.headers.host`. this means that the setting of `opts.host` is no use.

Comment: @SunnySun `opts.host` is the host where the request should be sent to, `opts.headers.host` sets the HTTP `Host` header for that request. Those aren't (strictly speaking) related.